# Как принимать POST/GET запросы в Python

Tags: python

Изучаю пайтон и очень хочу понять некоторые его основы.
Отправлять GET/POST ещё ладно, ничего сложного, хотел бы узнать, что и как нужно для того чтобы получать GET/POST запросы. В PHP с этим проблем никогда не было, просто заливаешь файл на хостинг и принимаешь $_GET/$_POST, как это работает в пайтоне?

Comment: Взять любой удобный веб-сервер (Django+gunicorn, Flask+uwsgi, starlette+uvicorn, aiohttp, sanic, blacksheep, что угодно ещё), прочитать их документацию, написать нужный код, запустить и радоваться жизни

Comment: да можно просто использовать `py http.server 8000` и у вас поднимется сервер способный принимать GET/POST запросы через http

Comment: @Dmitry да, но для продакшена не годится

Comment: @andreymal абсолютно, но для обучения или быстрых тестов может быть самое то)

Comment: как это всё примерно в коде выглядит?..

Comment: @MironDiamond примеры кода вы можете посмотреть в документации интересующего вас веб-сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соберу все в один ответ. Для того чтобы принимать запросы вы можете использовать следующее

1. Для тестовых запросов, переадресаций на локальной машине можете использовать данную команду из командной строки/терминала `py -m http.server 8000`. После того как вы запустите на исполнение будет доступен адрес `http://localhost:8000`
2. Фреймворки на python, которые позволяют разворачивать полноценные приложения - [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/), [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/). Имеют интерфейсы для работы как на на локальной машине через `localhost`, так и все необходимое для развертывания на удаленном сервере, используя Apache, NGINX, gunicorn и еще много всего разного в зависимости от ваших задач
3. Для REST можете использовать тот же `Django` и его мощный [Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) так же в связке с одним из веб-серверов (я по большей части NGINX и gunicorn использую). Или отойти немного в сторону и использовать [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)

Приведенный список не содержит исключительно всех решений, дополните меня. В списке указаны уже готовые решения и интерфейсы для создания необходимого функционала для тестирования развертывания веб приложений, используя python.

Стоит обратить внимание на стандарты [CGI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI) и [WCGI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSGI), которые определяют стандартные интерфейсы, которые могут быть использованы програмным обеспечением для обработки веб-запросов. `Django`, `Flask` поддерживают из коробки.